# Using environment variables within dependencies.yml?

Tags: dependencies, playframework

I'd like to know whether it's possible to use any other properties than the bundled one in the dependencies.yml configuration file.

For example, if I have a DEV_HOME environment variable, I'd like to be able to declare a repository location like this:

```
repositories:
    - local dev:
        type: local
        artifact: ${env.DEV_HOME}/repository/[module]
        contains:
            mycompany -> *
```

This way I would avoid the pain of installing and maintaining a Nexus proxy and just share repositories through an environment variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make the environment variable work, but it may be I did something wrong and it's totally possible (someone else can check?).

A possible solution to your problem is to use this to declare your repository:

```
repositories:
     - localModules:
         type:       local
         artifact:   "${application.path}/mods/[organisation]/[module]-[revision]/"
         contains:
           - custom
```

This will use a folder *mods* inside the root folder of your project as the location for your modules.

Comment: Thanks but it's actually not what I want to do as we'd like to have our own shared repository on different machine.
I couldn't find any way to do it other than going into the Play resolver and add a check with System.getenv in addition to the already existing System.getProperty call.

Comment: I understand your point, but in my case, some modules are reused for multiple customer projects and shouldn't be copied... Anyway, thanks for confirming this!

Comment: A little fix, for me works only: artifact: "file://${application.path}/..."

Answer (score 1):

Juste to share the trick I used (under MacOS, it should also work under Linux) is to create a symbolic link to this particular path.
Every other team member creates the same symbolic link to its own path and location so that everyone can put its own local repository wherever he wants.

I'll try to check whether I can propose some enhancement to the resolver when I'll have a chance.

Cheers